# What is this url path mean?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

Hello I am new to Django, I saw a line `path('dashboard/(?P<user>.*)/$'),` . I didn't understand this. I want to learn this part. But I don't know how to search on google and youtube about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this means the path for this url passes in a variable user within the link. So each page using this path will have 'dashboard/"the_user"/' in the address bar.

Comment: But I am getting path like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/(%3FPD.*)/$`. why?

Comment: @IstiakFahim That is ajax syntax basically representing your "user" value in that string. If you want to be more clear you could do path('dashboard/<str:user>/') assuming user is a string

Comment: which one is better way?

Comment: @IstiakFahim if you are new to django, my version is probably easier, you wouldnt have to learn ajax. But it is very useful later on as you expand your needs.

Answer (score 1):

> In Python regular expressions, the syntax for named regular expression groups is `(?P<name>pattern)`, where `name` is the name of the group and `pattern` is some pattern to match.

See the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions)